# Can't deserialize long in json with Moshi

Tags: android, json, moshi

I know it's a very silly question but I am experiencing a strange problem when deserializing with Moshi a Json

My Json has this field:

> "version":1499082281552

And in my pojo I have this field:

> private long version;

But I always get the error:

```
W/System.err: com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected an int but was 1499082281552 at path $.version
```

If in my json I have

> "version": 1498564139

everything works fine.

**UPDATE**:

Solved it. Should use a Long instead of long.

Comment: show the pojo class

Comment: Did you read the question? it is clear that field is `long`

Comment: The primitive long should work, too. Can you show the full code that didn't work?

Comment: If you want to you can post your update as an answer to your own question - that way it will show up as answered in the list.